# ROSPackageWizard in BRIDE

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to create a new project with the instructions in BRIDE:

File -> New -> Project

like in the link http://wiki.ros.org/bride/Tutorials/Creating-nodes-with-BRIDE-and-cplusplus

But in the Wizard list doesnt appears ROSPackageWizard... i need to import that package? or what i have to do to have the ROS package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199120/rospackagewizard-in-bride/) by [jav_greepo](https://answers.ros.org/users/21055/jav_greepo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-12-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my case, I solve that issue using ubuntu 14.04 LTS and ROS Indigo and Don't use virtual machines and having a dualcore processor.

---

Originally posted by [Netza](https://answers.ros.org/users/22082/netza/) with karma: 16 on 2015-04-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0